# Normalize whitespace and describe string

Tags: c#, strings, api

*The most valuable of all talents is that of never using two words when one will do. Thomas Jefferson.*

[NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/X.ComponentModel/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/x-utils/tree/e8082084758ae3a4d60c9c922b863d131bb50d2a)

I found it useful to automatically normalize string content a little bit and explicitly state what kind of content could be held in a field:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Normalize()
{
    var name = new Name(" Thomas ", null, "  Jefferson \n \r ");
    Assert.AreEqual("Thomas", name.First);
    Assert.AreEqual("", name.Middle);
    Assert.AreEqual("Jefferson", name.Last);
}
```

where test uses the following demo class:

```
class Name
{
    public Name(string first, string middle, string last)
        : this((Word)first, (WordOrEmpty)middle, (Word)last)
    {
    }

    public Name(Word first, WordOrEmpty middle, Word last)
    {
        First = first;
        Middle = middle;
        Last = last;
    }

    public Word First { get; }
    public WordOrEmpty Middle { get; }
    public Word Last { get; }
}
```

Library classes are:

```
public class Text : String<Text>, IEnumerable<Line>
{
    public static explicit operator Text(string text) => new Text(text);
    public Text(string text)
        : base(text, EmptyIfNull, Trim)
    {
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    public IEnumerator<Line> GetEnumerator() => Text
        .Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
        .Select(l => (Line)l)
        .GetEnumerator();
}
```

And:

```
public class Line : String<Line>, IEnumerable<Word>
{
    public static explicit operator Line(string text) => new Line(text);
    public Line(string text) 
        : base(text, EmptyIfNull, Trim, SpaceIfNewLine)
    {
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    public IEnumerator<Word> GetEnumerator() => Text
        .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(l => (Word)l)
        .GetEnumerator();
}
```

And:

```
public class LineOrNull : String<LineOrNull>, IEnumerable<Word>
{
    public static explicit operator LineOrNull(string text) => new LineOrNull(text);
    public LineOrNull(string text)
        : base(text, NullIfEmpty, Trim, SpaceIfNewLine)
    {
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    public IEnumerator<Word> GetEnumerator() => (Text ?? "")
        .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(l => (Word)l)
        .GetEnumerator();
}
```

And:

```
public class Word : String<Word>
{
    public static explicit operator Word(string text) => new Word(text);
    public Word(string text)
        : base(text, NotNullOrWhitespace, Trim, NotMultiline, NoSpace)
    {
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class WordOrNull : String<WordOrNull>
{
    public static explicit operator WordOrNull(string text) => new WordOrNull(text);
    public WordOrNull(string text)
        : base(text, Trim, NullIfEmpty, NotMultiline, NoSpace)
    {
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class WordOrEmpty : String<WordOrEmpty>
{
    public static explicit operator WordOrEmpty(string text) => new WordOrEmpty(text);
    public WordOrEmpty(string text)
        : base(text, Trim, EmptyIfNull, NotMultiline, NoSpace)
    {
    }
}
```

Where:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringJsonConverter))]
public abstract class String<T> : ValueObject<T>
    where T: String<T>
{
    protected static string Trim(string text) => text?.Trim();
    protected static string EmptyIfNull(string text) => text ?? Empty;
    protected static string NullIfEmpty(string text) => IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) ? null : text;
    protected static string SpaceIfNewLine(string text) => text
        ?.Replace("\n\r", " ")
        ?.Replace("\r\n", " ")
        ?.Replace("\r", " ")
        ?.Replace("\n", " ");            

    protected static string Upper(string text) => text?.ToUpper();
    protected static string Lower(string text) => text?.ToLower();

    protected static string NotNull(string text) =>
        text ?? throw new TextException();
    protected static string NotNullOrWhitespace(string text) =>
        IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) ? throw new TextException() :
        text;
    protected static string NotNullOrEmpty(string text) =>
        IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? throw new TextException() : 
        text;
    protected static string NoSpace(string text) =>
        text == null ? null :
        text.Contains(' ') ? throw new TextException() :
        text;
    protected static string NotMultiline(string text) =>
        text == null ? null :
        text.Contains('\n') || text.Contains('\r') ? throw new TextException() :
        text;

    public static implicit operator string(String<T> s) => s?.Text;

    protected String(string text, params Func<string, string>[] actions) => 
        Text = actions.Aggregate(text, (acc, f) => f(acc));

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => Text;

    protected override IEnumerable<object> EqualityCheckAttributes => 
        new[] { Text };
}
```

Where:

```
public class TextException : Exception
{
    public TextException([CallerMemberName] string rule = null)
        : base($"Must be {rule}.")
    {
    }
}
```

And:

```
class StringJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) =>
        objectType == typeof(object) ? false :
        objectType.IsConstructedGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(String<>) ? true :
        CanConvert(objectType.BaseType);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, reader.Value);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
}
```

And:

```
public abstract class ValueObject<T> : IEquatable<ValueObject<T>>
             where T : ValueObject<T>
{
    protected abstract IEnumerable<object> EqualityCheckAttributes { get; }

    public override int GetHashCode() =>
        EqualityCheckAttributes
            .Aggregate(0, (hash, a) => unchecked(hash * 31 + (a?.GetHashCode() ?? 0)));

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        Equals(obj as ValueObject<T>);

    public virtual bool Equals(ValueObject<T> other) =>
        other != null &&
        GetType() == other.GetType() &&
        EqualityCheckAttributes.SequenceEqual(other.EqualityCheckAttributes);

    public static bool operator ==(ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right) =>
        Equals(left, right);

    public static bool operator !=(ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right) =>
        !Equals(left, right);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind clarifying why you provide string overloads for the construct of `Name`? It's not clear to me why it should be the job of `Name` (or other similar classes) to normalise those inputs.

Comment: @VisualMelon compare to `StreamWriter` ctor overloads. It saves a bunch of typing by having a primitive type based overload, especially while unit testing.

Comment: @VisualMelon Though it is a little bit of "frameworkish", not so common for business object types where we are trying to get rid of all technical complexity. It asks for a partial class :)

Comment: I would _group_ the `static` helpers in nested classes like `Filters` and `Constraints` so their usage would be easier to understand like: `base(text, Filters.Trim, Filters.NullIfEmpty, Constraints.NotMultiline, Constraints.NoSpace)`

Comment: @t3chb0t How `Use.Trimmed`, `Use.NullIfEmpty` and `Only.NotMultiline` sound?

Comment: You're thinking about making it _fluent_? ;-] then we'll need to think harder :P

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed the edit... `Use` sounds much better... I could live with `Only`, sounds ok too.

Comment: @t3chb0t May be three: `Use`, `Only`, and `Not` :)

Comment: haha, I was going to suggest the same thing to get rid of the `Not` in some names.

Comment: I wonder why `Equals` needs this `GetType() == other.GetType()` condition? It works only with `ValueObject<T>` so they are always of the same type - this check is redundant, isn't it?

Comment: @t3chb0t there is no limit of the inheritance depth captured in VO<T>, while value equality semantics requires type equality. It is a well documented pattern - you could read about it [here](https://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Principles-Practices-Domain-Driven-Design/dp/1118714709/).

Comment: I even own this book o_O bought it once and forgot about it LOL - I'd be very nice if you could give me the pattern's name ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t No surprise here - Chapter 15: Value Objects :)  You could also have a look at Pluralsight [course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/csharp-equality-comparisons/) on Equality and Comparisons - equality is tricky when inheritance is involved.

Comment: ok, I looked at that chapter and I find my solution is much better, especially that their examples are only examples and they suggest using reflection or other techniques anyway. I also find it's weird that they do not use `yield return` in their attribute enumerators but create arrays and that the `ValueObject<T>` does not implement `IEquatable<>` which you have already addressed ;-] Overall it's a good starting point and inspiration that certainly requires adding the `IEqualityComparer<T>` and using a different technique from `SequenceEqual` which is very weak in the long run.

Comment: ...and I need to look at the other chapters too... lot's of interesting stuff there but I guess they are only basics that need to be made production-ready first ;-] If they made it bullet-proof they could just have made it a NuGet package :P

Comment: @t3chb0t Actually, I found this `VO<T>` a very useful tool as it is. It just keeps all technical stuff away in the base type without polluting business object itself. You could also find a good explanation of redundancy of `IEquitable<T> where T: class` in that Pluralsight video. `IEquitable<T>` was mostly introduced to prevent boxing of value types...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have much to say, but this stuff does look useful. The types are designed to be exposed to the world, so it's transparent to the consumer and could make the intentions clear.

There is one huge problem:

```
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Anyone can change this value and by-pass all the rules: I assume this is a typo and you intended for this to be getter-only.

### General Stuff

This all needs documenting, to explain what the different classes do. `SpaceIfNewLine` is one example that baffles me completely: I would expect `Line` to fail if someone threw a complete text at it. I don't like this behaviour, because we shouldn't allow the user to accidently overlook that and give them nonsensical but meaningful results to trip over later (fail fast and all that); if you want this behaviour, then it must be documented clearly. `NotMultiline` and `NoSpace` with `Word` make much more sense to me.

I don't like how you swap `null` or `""` and vice-versa in places. Perhaps this is completely necessary in your domain, but receiving a `null` all too often indicates a programming error (not necessarily on the part of the component that produces the `null` originally), and quietly coercing it obscures this from the caller.

The behaviour of `ValueObject<T>` really needs documentating: it is completely opaque to the consumer, and will create confusion if someone extends a class that extends it. `Word` etc. should probably be `sealed`.

### Exceptions

The exceptions this produces will be cryptic: "Must be IsNullOrEmpty". I would ditch the `CallerMemberName` stuff and just force yourself to write a clear message, or atleast change it to $"String value violates rule {rule}" (where the grammar won't go funky) and rename it to a `TextRuleViolationException`, or something like that: it shoudn't be used by things that aren't 'rules', because then the message would be meaningless.

Buffering the `CallerMemberName` bit inside a `TextException Violated(string rule)` method in `String<T>` would avoid misuse of this otherwise public API from outside, and save you typing `new` in each rule, which you seem to be very keep to avoid.

There is also no provision for informing the user *what* was in violation: as it `first` or `last` that went wrong when I tried to create my name? Your code cannot adequately support the stringy constructor for `Name` (which I don't think should exist anyway) without some addition method to perform the conversion, catch the exception, and annotate it with the parameter name.